# Youtube video player inside app(which plays inside webview itself)

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I am trying to make `Youtube video player` inside app(which plays video inside `webview` itself).Is there any tutorials based on this.or any sample Program ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed youtube vids in a webview like this:

```
- (void)embedYouTubeInWebView:(NSString*)url theWebView:(UIWebView *)aWebView {     

NSString *embedHTML = @"\
<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {\

background-color: transparent;\
color: white;\
}\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
</body></html>";

NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, aWebView.frame.size.width, aWebView.frame.size.height]; 

[aWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
}
```